# Flow | Redux | Can't pass StateProps and DispatchProps to connect function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype

Flow declaration for redux connect function is the following:

```js
declare export function connect<-P, -OP, -SP, -DP, S, D>(
  // ...
)
```

it's taken from:
https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-redux_v7.x.x/flow_v0.104.x-/react-redux_v7.x.x.js

Please correct me if I wrong:

- `P` - stands for **Props**. Just all props that component should eventually receive.
- `OP` - stands for **OwnProps**. Props that should be passed to connected component(i.e. not derived from the state).
- `SP` - stands for **StateProps**. Props that are derived from state, which `mapStateToProps` must return.
- `DP` - stands for **DispatchProps**. Props that are derived from dispatch, which `mapDispatchToProps` must return.
- `S` - stands for **State**. Type of state to pass in `mapStateToProps`.
- `D` - stands for **Dispatch**. Type of dispatch to pass in `mapDispatchToProps`.

If all the above statements are correct, then everything seems clear and logical to me.

So, when I'm trying to pass those generics:

```js
/* @flow */

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as ActionCreators from './actionCreators';
import type { Todo } from './types';
import type { State } from './reducers';

type OwnProps = {||};

type StateProps = {|
  +todos: Array<Todo>;
|};

type DispatchProps = $ReadOnly<typeof ActionCreators>

type Props = {|
  ...OwnProps;
  ...StateProps;
  ...DispatchProps;
|};

export const TodoList = (props: Props) => (
  <div>
    // ...
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state: State) => ({
  todos: state.visibleTodos,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = ActionCreators; // redux will automatically call `bindActionCreators`

export default connect<Props, OwnProps, StateProps, DispatchProps, State, _>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList);
```

I get the following output from flow, why?

```
Cannot call connect because:
 - Either property todos is missing in object type [1] but exists in StateProps [2] in type argument SP.
 - Or property addTodo is missing in object type [3] but exists in DispatchProps [4] in type argument DP.
 - Or property todos is missing in object type [5] but exists in StateProps [2] in type argument SP.
 - Or property todos is missing in object type [6] but exists in StateProps [2] in type argument SP.

        src/components/TodoList/index.jsx
         72|
         73| const mapDispatchToProps = ActionCreators;
         74|
 [2][4]  75| export default connect<Props, OwnProps, StateProps, DispatchProps, State, _>(
         76|   mapStateToProps,
         77|   mapDispatchToProps,
         78| )(TodoList);

        flow-typed/npm/react-redux_v7.x.x.js
    [1] 148|   declare export function connect<-P, -OP, -SP: {||}, -DP: {||}, S, D>(
           :
    [3] 156|   declare export function connect<-P, -OP, -SP, -DP: {||}, S, D>(
           :
    [5] 166|   declare export function connect<-P, -OP, -SP: {||}, -DP, S, D>(
           :
    [6] 176|   declare export function connect<-P, -OP, -SP: {||}, -DP, S, D>(

Found 1 error
```

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that's the flow bug with type inference. I solved this problem by explicitly adding `StateProps` return type to `mapStateToProps`.